# What is the main advantage of HTML table compared to Grid View in Asp.net

Tags: c#

What is the main advantage of HTML table comparing to Grid View  in Asp.net?

Answer (score 2):

GridView is the server control and will be rendered as a html table structure when it is displayed in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

1. Grid View rendering at browser is in HTML table format only.
2. Grid View is server side control.